# Triangle Inequalities

Tags: inequality

Anybody have a hint on how to begin to Prove that $\lvert x-y \rvert \lvert z-w \rvert \leq \lvert x-z \rvert \lvert y-w \rvert + \lvert x-w \rvert \lvert y-z \rvert$ for any $w,x,y,z \in \Bbb R$?

Comment: As stated, the equality is false. Take $x = y = 0$, $w = z = 1$. Then the left hand side is $0$, while the right hand side is $1\cdot 1 + 1 \cdot 1 = 2$.

Comment: Presumably the author meant $\le$ instead of $=$.

Comment: Now that I have fixed the initial inequality, how can we proceed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$|(xy-xw-yz+zw)+(xz-xy-zw+yw)|\le|xy-xw-yz+zw|+|xz-xy-zw+yw|$

Comment: Pretty much the only way to go (+1)

Comment: Awesome! A bit of manipulation can work wonders.